# QT : Using lambda in a connect statement - VS2012

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to use this statement . I am using QT 5.1 in VS2012

```
connect(ui.pushButton_next, SIGNAL(clicked()), []{
    std::cout << "clicked" << std::endl;
});
```

I get

> error C2664: 'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject
>   *,const char *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType) const' : cannot convert parameter 3 from
>   'newAccount::{ctor}::' to
>   'const char *' 1>          No user-defined-conversion operator
>   available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be
>   called

Any suggestion on what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: Isn't `ui` a pointer? And NO, you cannot use the old syntax with a lambda, you have to use the new connect syntax.

Comment: ui is an object that has the pointer pushbutton_next

Comment: You aren't using a designer form then, because the `ui` that Qt generates in such cases is a pointer.

Comment: I am using VStudio plugin

Comment: You can still use designer from VS with the VS add-on. My point was that if it is the generated `ui`, then it is a pointer, but you seem to have created a `ui` object of your own.

Comment: Take a look at this page here, it explains the new connection syntax in Qt5 http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Looking at the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#connect), the overloads of the connect method that support the SIGNAL and SLOT macros do not appear to take in a Functor object - this is only supported by [this overload](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#connect-5) that takes in a PointerToMemberFunction.

The right syntax for your code is:

```
connect(ui.pushButton_next, &QObject::clicked, []{
    std::cout << "clicked" << std::endl;
});
```